# How to override a template file in module creation in Magento2

Tags: magento2

I want to override :

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml
```

I have copied and pasted it in my custom module at :

```
app/code/Hello/Custom/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml
```

This is my Layout file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart" template="Hello_Custom::product/view/addtocart.phtml" after="alert.urls">
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

at:

```
app/code/Hello/Custom/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
```

module.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Hello_Custom" setup_version="1.0.0" schema_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

- Module is working for simple hello world so its registered correctly ...

The issue is in template path hints file comes from vendor..
but it should come from my custom module only (not from theme)

Comment: is catalog_product_view.xml naming is essential or we can give any name to file. actually I need help on overriding template

Comment: siddhesh the naming of that file is definitely essential. It determines where the layout file is loaded. For example `default.xml` is loaded on every page but `catalog_product_view.xml` is only loaded on the `catalog/product/view` action.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

you can try with below code in xml file,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Hello_Custom::product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
         </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Yes definitely ..

Comment: how to check if layout xml file is used or not? i  tried to write invalid xml and still my page was rendered correctly . so I concluded my xml layout file is not executed  do you tell me how to solve this

Comment: or do we need to run some kind of commands after updating xml file

Comment: Actually, in the [dev docs of magento 2](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html) you can read  "using the <action> instruction. **This way is not recommended**, but can be used for... ". I would recommend using the method suggested on that page under **Set a block template**. So using the action to change the template is not a good solution.

Answer (score 14):

There are three methods available to override template files in Magento

For example: Here we override **addtocart.phtml** file for simple product.

**Method 1:**

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</referenceContainer>
```

**Method 2:**

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart" template="Vendor_Module::product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

**Method 3:**

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.form.content">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="Vendor_Module::product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1. using the `<argument>` instruction

```
<referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">%Namespace_Module::new_template.phtml%</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

Solution 2. using the `template` attribute

```
<referenceBlock name="page.main.title" template="%Namespace_Module::new_template.phtml%"/>
```

Solution 3. using the `<action method="setTemplate">` instruction

```
<referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
   <action method="setTemplate">
     <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">%Namespace_Module::new_template.phtml%</argument>
   </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

**The override priority is 1 < 2 < 3.**