# how to override customer login.phtml file in custom module

Tags: magento2, frontend, customer-account

I want to override Customer login form of core files. In `customer/account/login` xml file I already added my custom file path and override it , but still it is not working.

How can i override **form/login.phtml** file ?

please help me....

xml => **customer_account_login.xml**

```
<referenceBlock name="customer_form_login">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Name_Abc::form/login.phtml
                </argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
```

Comment: Please share your full code of file here

Answer (score 3):

inside your  `customer_account_login.xml` file,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <container name="customer.login.container" before="customer_form_register" label="Customer Login Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="login-container">
                <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login" name="customer_form_login" template="Name_Abc::form/login.phtml">
                    <container name="form.additional.info" as="form_additional_info"/>
                </block>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
  </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Above code try, clear cache and let me know.

Comment: not working :( @Rakesh

Comment: Just updated answer and please let me know after clear cache.

Comment: please let me know if you have still issue

Comment: Still Not Working :(

Answer (score 1):

In your `customer_account_login.xml` file,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="customer.login.container">
            <referenceBlock name="customer_form_login">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Prince_Productattach::test.phtml</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Not working ....  @PrincePatel

Comment: I already try it...

Comment: @RohanHapani check updated answer you customer_account_login like this, flush cache and let me know if not working

Comment: Still Not Working :(

Comment: @RohanHapani check my answer this are all three methods to override phtml file https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/175825/35758

Comment: Your welcome....@Rohan Hapani

Comment: Still I have not getting my output ...so i am not accept your answer :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59216/discussion-between-prince-patel-and-rohan-hapani).

Answer (score 0):

Add referenceContainer in your xml file and update this code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="customer.login.container">
            <referenceBlock name="customer_form_login">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Prince_Productattach::test.phtml</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Hope it may be useful for you

Answer (score 0):

Update this code in your `customer_account_login.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <container name="customer.login.container" before="customer_form_register" label="Customer Login Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="login-container">
                <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login" name="customer_form_login" template="Name_Abc::form/login.phtml">
                    <container name="form.additional.info" as="form_additional_info"/>
                </block>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
  </body>
</page>
```

It may be useful for you.